# Parsing STARTUPINFO hStdInput before executing

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi

I'm trying to write a simple remote shell using C++ and would like to be able to parse commands before executing them, my problem is that the hStdInput gets the input directly from a WSASocket handle thus it automatically executes the command on the remote machine, is there a way to parse the hStdInput and act accordingly? or maybe do it another way?

Here is a code snippet:

```
sinfo.dwFlags = (STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW);
sinfo.hStdInput = sinfo.hStdOutput = sinfo.hStdError = (HANDLE)mySocket;
CreateProcess(NULL, Process, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &sinfo, &pinfo);
WaitForSingleObject(pinfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(pinfo.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pinfo.hThread);
```

Comment: Then don't use socket handle for `hStdInput`, attach pipe instead and then transfer stuff from that pipe to socket after processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CreatePipe` to create an anonymous pipe that you connect to the child process instead of connecting the socket to it directly.

```
HANDLE read_pipe, write_pipe;
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
CreatePipe(&read_pipe, &write_pipe, &sa, 0);

sinfo.hStdInput = read_pipe;
sinfo.hStdOutput = sinfo.hStdError = (HANDLE)mySocket;

CreateProcess(NULL, Process, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &sinfo, &pinfo);
HANDLE handles[2] = {pinfo.hProcess, mySocket};

char buffer[1024];
while(true) {
    DWORD wfmo = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, handles, FALSE, INFINITE);
    if(wfmo == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
        // process died
        break;
    } else if(wfmo == WAIT_OBJECT_0+1) {
        // read socket and write to write_pipe
        DWORD NumberOfBytesRead;
        DWORD NumberOfBytesWritten;
        if(ReadFile(mySocket, buffer, 1024, &NumberOfBytesRead, NULL)) {
            char* bptr = buffer;
            while(NumberOfBytesRead) {
                if(WriteFile(write_pipe, bptr, NumberOfBytesRead, &NumberOfBytesWritten, NULL)) {
                    bptr += NumberOfBytesWritten;
                    NumberOfBytesRead -= NumberOfBytesWritten;
                } else {
                    // write failed
                }
            }
        } else {
            // read failed
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186686/discussion-on-answer-by-ted-lyngmo-parsing-startupinfo-hstdinput-before-executin).